# Why is ssh-agent not starting?

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

When I type the command $eval "$(ssh-agent -s)" to start ssh and be able to register my keys I get the following error:

`1 [main] ssh-agent 437 dofork: child -1 - forked process 628 died unexpectedly, retry 0, exit code 0xC0000005, errno 11 fork: Resource temporarily unavailable`

Comment: Try `eval \`ssh-agent\``.